# How to Compile projects in another console application

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Place all output dlls in common directory from Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297427/place-all-output-dlls-in-common-directory-from-visual-studio)

I have a solution which is having 15 projects.
Now i want to compile all these project and save dlls into another location using another console application.

Comment: There is a lot of questions on this topic, use search. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297427/place-all-output-dlls-in-common-directory-from-visual-studio

Comment: Try using the [MSBuild Command Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) in a batch file or using the [System.Diagnostic.Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) or [Nant](http://nant.sourceforge.net/)